# How to select checkbox and font awesome elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, font-awesome

JQuery makes it easy to select an element by ID or classname but this is a bit beyond my knowledge.

I have the following styles I want applied when a function is called.

```
.classname input[type="checkbox"] ~ i.fa.fa-circle-o {
     color: grey;
}


.classname input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ i.fa.fa-check-circle-o {
     color: grey;
}
```

So I tried putting them inside a function like this:

```
function greyOut(classname) {
    console.log("fired");

    $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox'] ~ i.fa.fa-circle-o").css("color: grey");
    $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ i.fa.fa-check-circle-o").css("color: grey");
}
```

But this is not working at all. The function fired but no change in color for those elements and no error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it's just bad jQuery syntax. When you are changin in `.css()` method just oen property, you must use another syntax. So, you have these two possibilities:

```
function greyOut(classname) {
  console.log("fired");
  $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox'] ~ i.fa.fa-circle-o").css("color", "grey");
  $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ i.fa.fa-check-circle-o").css("color", "grey");
}
```

Or:

```
function greyOut(classname) {
  console.log("fired");
  $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox'] ~ i.fa.fa-circle-o").css({color: 'grey'});
  $("." + classname + " input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ i.fa.fa-check-circle-o").css({color: 'grey'});
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the first approach and my approach?

Comment: @kevin_b Look carefully for differences: you are trying this: `.css("color: grey")`, I am showing this: `.css("color", "grey")`, or this `.css({color: grey})`.

Comment: Ahh nice this is great

Comment: Of the two which do you recommend

Comment: I'd recommend using classes with `.addClass` ... but if you're adamant to use `.css` then use `.css({key:value})` as you can add other attributes more easily `.css({color:"grey", "background-color":"red"})`

Comment: @kevin_b Doe's not matter. It supports two syntaxes, because if you want change just one property, you have these two options, but if you want change more properties once, then you literally MUST use only second syntax: `.css({color: 'grey', backgroundColor: 'blue'})`. And as you can see, you must use JS property names, not CSS. So, for example: `backgroundColor`, or `fontSize`, instead of `background-color` or `font-size`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simplify your code by using `addClass()` instead?

Example:

```js
function greyOut(classname) {
  $(classname).addClass("checked");
}
```

```css
.classname.checked input[type="checkbox"]~i.fa.fa-circle-o,
.classname.checked input[type="checkbox"]:checked~i.fa.fa-check-circle-o {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="classname">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```